# Apache Httpd/WebGate truncates 1% of pages

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, weblogic

We have the followign setup:

> WebLogic 9 Portal Server <-> Apache
>   HTTPD/WebGate <-> Clients

When cliens are accessing portal through Apache proxy, then about 1% of requests are truncated in the browser i.e. only partial HTML result is displayed. When portal is accessed directly all requests are served OK and fully.

I know it's a bit wide description, but may be someone can point me in the right direction to look at.

One more thing I can add is that access.log's on the Portal and Apache servers report full size response to be served i.e. transfered byte count matches on both servers.

Portal and Apache are deployed on different physical servers.

Comment: Are the garbled results on https by any chance? Also - any firewall in between Apache different from the Weblogic setup? If the byte size shown is correct in Apache, then it has responded correctly - so whatever happens after that is on the network between the server and browser.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's plain http. There is definetly additional router/firewall there in between, but we are not controlling set up of that and the guys behind the setup reject any reports from us saying that firewall is ok. And as they calim it's the same firewall/router protecting both servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appeared to be a problem with a custom proxy returning wrong Content-Length header in response which confused the browser.

Comment: +1 - thanks for coming back to provide an answer!